# Как добавить класс input'у при заполнении данными?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача стоит такова, что бы подсказка в input поле была сверху, если пользователь заполнил поле, для этого мне надо добавить класс если value у input заполнен:

```css
.contacts-form {
  padding: 32px 54px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.ui-group {
  position: relative;
}

.ui-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 12px 0 0;
  border: 0 solid #E1F5F2;
  border: 0 solid #6BC5D2;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #390050;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.ui-field:focus+.ui-placeholder {
  margin-right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-placeholder {
  margin-right: 4px;
  top: 23px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9B8EA0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s ease;
}

.ui-placeholder::before {
  content: '*';
  display: inline;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="contacts-form">
  <div class="ui-group">
    <input type="text" class="ui-field" id="name" value="">
    <label for="name" class="ui-placeholder">Имя</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS:

```
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("change", function(){
  if(this.value.length){
   this.classList.add('ui-placeholder');
   }else{
   this.classList.remove('ui-placeholder');
   }
});
```

JQuery : если я правельно понял какой класс добавить..

```js
$("#name").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val().trim().length) {
    $(this).addClass("ui-placeholder");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-placeholder");
  }
})
```

```css
.contacts-form {
  padding: 32px 54px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.ui-group {
  position: relative;
}

.ui-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 12px 0 0;
  border: 0 solid #E1F5F2;
  border: 0 solid #6BC5D2;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #390050;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.ui-field:focus+.ui-placeholder {
  margin-right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-placeholder {
  margin-right: 4px;
  top: 23px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9B8EA0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s ease;
}

.ui-placeholder::before {
  content: '*';
  display: inline;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="contacts-form">
  <div class="ui-group">
    <input type="text" class="ui-field" id="name" value="">
    <label for="name" class="ui-placeholder">Имя</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно! Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 2):

можно еще так

```js
    var uiField = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-field')[0];
    uiField.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
           
        if (uiField.value.length >= 1) {
            uiField.classList.add('ui-field-active');
        }else{   
            uiField.classList.remove('ui-field-active');
        }
    })
```

```css
.contacts-form {
  padding: 32px 54px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.ui-group {
  position: relative;
}

.ui-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 12px 0 0;
  border: 0 solid #E1F5F2;
  border: 0 solid #6BC5D2;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #390050;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.ui-field:focus+.ui-placeholder {
  margin-right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-placeholder {
  margin-right: 4px;
  top: 23px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9B8EA0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .3s ease;
}

.ui-placeholder::before {
  content: '*';
  display: inline;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.ui-field-active{
    
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="contacts-form">
  <div class="ui-group">
    <input type="text" class="ui-field" id="name" value="">
    <label for="name" class="ui-placeholder">Имя</label>
  </div>
</form>
```