# Помогите создать плагин, чтобы placeholder в input убегал вверх, как и в телеграм

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Нужно сделать плагин, чтобы было так, как на картинке, был бы очень благодарен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить класс input'у при заполнении данными?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712646/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-input%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 4):

А уже все реализовано, чтобы не велосипедить, посмотри на **MUI - Material Design CSS Framework** (http://muicss.com), там же можешь посмотреть как это сделать самому.

Вот еще ссылка на сам репозиторий: https://github.com/muicss/mui