# Стилизация атрибута value

Tags: html, css, input

UPD: Проблема только в Safari, никак не хочет меняться.

Имеется input с атрибутом "value='0'", которым в дальнейшем я оперирую в JS. По умолчанию цвет этого ноля и соответственно дальнейших вводимых значений - приглушенный серый, и мне нужно заменить его. Не могу найти решение, как это сделать.

```
<input class="calc_display" value="0"  id="display" type="text" disabled>
<style>

   input {
   margin-top: 27%;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: #181818;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 5.5em;
   text-align: right;
   width: 100%;
   border: none;
   }

</style>
```

Comment: пока вводите хотите один цвет, а по прекращению другой?

Comment: input disabled без возможности ввода текста.

Comment: а причём тут цвет, я не понимаю вопроса

Comment: Это поле в калькуляторе, куда выводится результат расчетов. Когда убираю disabled, ноль окрашивается в нужный цвет, добавляю - снова серый.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить класс input'у при заполнении данными?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712646/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-input%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тут помогло бы добавить стиль отдельно для состояния `disabled` и обычного состояния.

Вот пример:

```js
$("button").on('click', function(event) {
  var $this = $('.calc_display');
  if ($this.attr('disabled')) $this.removeAttr('disabled');
  else $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

```css
input:disabled {
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #181818;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

input {
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="calc_display" value="0" id="display" type="text" disabled>
<button>Toggle disabled</button>
```

Comment: это работает почему-то со всеми свойствами, кроме color))

Comment: @ArinaS Странно, а `!important` не помогает? И почему `color` не меняется? Вроде как должно не?

Comment: перепроверила. Не работает только в Safari. В Chrome все ок.